# Could water be converted into hydrogen and oxygen using very strong magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, water, polarization, hydrogen

Had a crazy thought experiment and was wondering if this is possible/feasible. You place water in a electrically neutral container like glass. Then the glass container is placed between two opposing poles of magnets (similar to how the magnets are arranged in a traditional electric motor). Since water is polar, my intuition tells me that the negative pole of the water molecule will be attracted to one magnet while the positive pole would be attracted to the other magnet. This should create "tension" in the bond between hydrogen and oxygen. Could you have strong enough magnets to break the bond?

Perhaps I am missing something or thinking of this the wrong way. Any help would be great!

Comment: Regardless of how you split the hydrogen from the oxygen, a minimum (and large) amount of energy must be put into the water molecule to perform the split.

Comment: Yes the spontaneous reaction H2+1/2 O2 gives H2O can be reversed by changing the temperature. Typically increasing the temperature. Gibbs=enthalpy-TS Reactions can be reversed but temperature, pressure, electric and magnetic fields

Answer (score 3):

It is true that [water molecules have an electric dipole moment](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/diph2o.html), making them align somewhat to external electric fields. But this does not mean they will be subjected to forces by magnetic fields unless they move very rapidly (since the force is proportional to field strength, velocity and charge, and the charge imbalance involved is very small here). So there is no effect from the polarity.

Some molecules have magnetic moments, and those would presumably respond more strongly. But water is weakly [diamagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism) $\chi = -9.0 \times 10^{-6}$, and molecules of diamagnetic materials have zero magnetic moment. So not much luck there either.

The "trick" is of course to shake the electromagnetic field so that you get heating from excitation and induced currents that eventually turns everything into a plasma. But there are easier ways of doing electrolysis.

Comment: The chemical potential is a function of both the magnetic and electric field and determines the Gibbs free energy ie whether a reaction happens in forward or reverse. In MRI technology hydrogen atoms are in a magnetic field and perturbed to flip spin directions by a radiowave pulse. The shift in the expected signal returned from the perturbation is based upon the chemistry of the neighboring atoms and is used in spectroscopy such as NMR spectroscopy. It has been publicly documented that even in magnetic fields as low as the earths magnetic field squids have been used to create MRI images.

Comment: @ChemEng MRI is the acronym that replaced NMR (_Nuclear_ Magnetic Resonance) because "nuclear" frightened patients, while everyone loves magnets. So it's the proton spin flip, not the hydrogen atom, that drives the signal.

Comment: @ChemEng - So, how strong does the magnetic field have to be to cause an appreciable dissociation of water because of a shift in the Gibbs free energy? Note that MRI/NMR acts on bound hydrogen atoms, not causing any dissociation.

Comment: @JEB yes a proton is the nucleus of the hydrogen atom ) normal isotope) and for molecules with one electron in the lone pair(paramagnetic materials) we can also see electron spectroscopy NMR. But yes if either of the number of protons or number of neutrons are odd we can expect a NMR signal

Comment: @anderssandberg I do not have access to that information. I could try using a neodyium magnet and a battery to electrolyse some water and compare the current to normal conditions. Still the butler volmer equation typically relates the voltage, temperature and the current independently with more sophisticated versions also including the effects of concentration to predict things such as the limiting current

Comment: Typically the decomposition potential is found using the nernst equation $$ \Delta G=-nFE=\mu dN=function of concentration temperature and equilibrium constant $$ how fast the reaction is,whether spontaneous discharge or electrolysis is found through the butler volmer equation a function of the difference between the E found from nernst and the actual voltage(known as the overpotential which is negative for discharge and positive for electrolysis)and the temperature. But we know the chemical potential is a function of the magnetic field thus its probably a compound term with the electric field

Comment: @ChemEng - As far as I have been able to see in the literature there isn't much of an effect. This paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230554064_Magnetic_Field_Effect_on_the_Kinetics_of_Oxygen_Dissolution_into_Water found a mild effect on oxygen solvability at 10T but would have noticed if there was any electrolysis. Remember that the energy shift has to be enough to overcome the entalphy of formation of water from the gases, quite a lot.

Comment: The Chemical potential mu has Magnetic and electric field dependence but not as an independent and (if I had to guess) ie the magnetic and electric field amplitudes are multiplying or dividing each other not adding or subtracting

Comment: @andersandberg yes it is my belief it is a compound term. Meaning that the presence of a 10T magnetic field will decrease or increase the voltage required to decompose the water. The only factors that are not constants in the relevant equations are the charge transfer coefficients(have to add up to 1) and the equilibrium constant. This is neglecting the effect of the magnetic field in the current as well

Comment: @ChemEng - Note that the question was about pure magnetic fields. There are papers looking at electrolysis efficiency increasing in magnetic fields, but the explanation looks more like bubble MHD than anything molecular.