# How strong of an MRI machine would be able to kill a person?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, estimation, magnetic-moment, biology

Previous title: How strong of a magnetic field could dissociate water molecules?
(Changed as this is probably not possible)

This is part of an attempt to answer the question 'How much MRI is enough to kill a person?'. I've found the extreme answers (that 16T is enough to levitate a frog and 1 million T would instantly kill you and break chemistry as a whole), but now I'm trying to find the in-between of exactly how much is required before a person dies. I have already read the following discussions on here and on other sites:
https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1asgy5/can_you_die_from_a_magnet_how_strong_does_it_have/

[Effects of a very large magnetic field on the human body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61679/effects-of-a-very-large-magnetic-field-on-the-human-body)

[Is it possible to kill a human with a powerful magnet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119999/396834)

<strike>These have led me to assume that the human body is 100% water, and I want to base my calculations on this. This now means I need to find out how much magnetic field is needed to break apart water molecules, as I imagine breaking up all the water in the body would probably be bad. However, I'm really struggling to find anything as most answers seem to focus on the idea of levitating water rather than pulling it apart. Is it even theoretically possible, or should I be taking a different approach?</strike>

I have been informed that this is, in fact, probably not possible, so I will need suggestions on how to approach this a different way as I'm really not sure how to do this at this point.

I promise this investigation is for educational purposes only.

Comment: Welcome upbeatmeeting to Physics Stack Exchange. The question assumes that a strong enough magnetic field could break apart water molecules. Even if this is explained in the links, it is best to briefly summarize the reasons why here. You might also want to reference ["Could water be converted into hydrogen and oxygen using very strong magnetic fields?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/659679/145491).

Comment: @DavidBailey Thanks for this, it looks like I'm going to need to change my approach to something else. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: You can infer it from the potential of the lipid barrier. I did this calculation at some point, roughly. The conclusion was that a magnet like that does not exist in nature. The exact number I don't remember. BTW, I would not call this "to kill a person". It sounds kind of... inhumane. I assume, you have some other, more scientific, motivation to ask this question.